# HtppWebRequest redirecting me to login even when I am logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httpwebrequest, forms-authentication

What I am trying to do :

1. Login to a Forms Auth MVC website using the normal login method/page
2. After I am logged in and I am on the home page, I want to send an ajax request to a controller->action which requests a webpage using HttpWebRequest object.

The problem is the response I get is the login page. which means HttpWebRequest is not honoring the fact that I am logged on to the website physically.

The problem is that I need to read the local cookies on my system and send them with my request. The cookie container is empty below. So, all I am asking for is a way to populate the CookieContainer with whatever cookies are on my machine.

```
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        String URL = "http://mysite.com/pages/fakepage.aspx";
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

The responseData above contains the login page :(

Comment: See it in chrome and if chrome shows that you are still logged in. I would suspect your routing

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the question for anyone stuck with the same issue. If you notice below, I am just reading the cookies from the Request object and populating my CookieContainer with it. That takes care of all the issues!

```
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    for(int i=0; i<Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
        webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(Request.Cookies[i].Name, Request.Cookies[i].Value, Request.Cookies[i].Path, FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain));
```